# Can routes on two separate laravel app on the same server have same name

Tags: php, laravel-7, ubuntu-20.04

I have a laravel 7 web app running smoothly on a Ubuntu Server.
For some reason the client wants me to make the same project (with some minor front end changes like logo, homepage, etc) available on a different domain name.
We want to use the same server for both the websites since the app is heavily dependent on many customization to the server itself.

I have created a new virtual host and the other domain serves from the correct directory.

However, when I try to do `php artisan route:cache` I get an error
`Unable to prepare route [profile/{username}/updateUserAccount] for serialization. Another route has already been assigned name [{username}].  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/AbstractRouteCollection.php:212` And the `homepage` gives a 404 error with `phpdebugbar` emitting the routes error.

As far as I remember I have not assigned any other route with the same name. The same codebase works fine from the other directory (same server but different domain).

I do not know much about the internals of laravel and this was my first full scale project on laravel. So I am wondering if the route names are supposed to be unique globally or is their scope limited to the specific laravel app.

Note: Using Laravel 7 on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: One Laravel project = One Domain....which can have n number of sub-domains.Each laravel project require single dedicated domain.For same domain and muliple project requires some changes in domain like sub-domain or sub-url.

Comment: Domains are different but app is same. Are there any laravel specific settings when setting up different domains? Apache vhost is setup correctly... Looks like a lot more to learn here... :)

Comment: Have you checked this bit https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#route-group-subdomain-routing ???